# Idiom or Synonym for Someone who looks/feels like you could trust them, like they are someone reliable?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, synonyms, idiom-requests

I'm writing a character description, and the person I'm describing looks and/or feels like someone you can trust, like someone who would be honest with you, someone innocent, maybe even pure. Even if you just met them. 
You just have the feeling like anything they say or do is with honest and good intentions and in case something they said or did come out as a lie, as something wrong you still feel the same somehow.
It would take something big to change your mind or else you would just think that they didn't mean it like that.

And it doesn't matter if the really didn't mean it or not. 
I do not mean someone who pretends to be trustable, in this case you don't know if they are what they seem to be or not. So please keep that in mind.

I knew a word, description, idiom or synonym that just fit, but I can't seem to remember. Please help?

Thankful,
Aina

Comment: Trustworthy, loyal, conscientious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This person can be [dependable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dependable), [genuine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genuine), [authentic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/authentic), or [sincere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sincere) if you feel they're always being honest and true with you.  These have positive connotations.

If despite their actions you feel compelled to still trust them, they could be [mesmerizing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mesmerizing) or [enchanting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enchant).  These have more of a supernatural if not negative connotation.

Comment: I don't get this dv.

Answer (score 0):

Google: **Soulmate**. "A soulmate is someone that just gets you. It's a connection of minds, a mutual respect, an unconditional love and a total understanding. It's about being yourself and knowing, not only that person is following and understanding your thoughts, but is right there with you, side by side. ... My sister is my soulmate.